# Flot identical range ticks

Tags: jquery, graph, plot, flot

Hi i want to add ticks that are not in a fixed range. i.e my ticks will be 1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5 how would i tell a data set for the graph type to plot points based on the tick number, instead of a fixed range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, what i did was in my ticks I set an array with an incrementing range from 0,1,n(+1) and set its label to whatever I want @0 = '27', @1 = '56', @2 = '67' ...etc and for my data sets on the x-axis point I filled it out based on my incrementing range.

Comment: I have a similar dilemma (actually, a few. But one at a time.)  Do you know if it's possible to add ticks rather than replace them? The API makes it seem like you can either use the default or make your own, but since I'm using zooming (and date ranges) I'm fine with the default, I just want to make sure some extra ticks get added. (for instance, when the user zooms in, I want it to switch to hours, but leave the dates at midnight).